# Data function not working react native firestore

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, puzzle

I got stuck in this puzzle which doesn't seem to wanna be solved, I am kinda sure I am forgetting something since I just started learning react-native.

I have this code :

```js
async componentDidMount() {
    let user = await UserRepository.getUserRef(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);
    await firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("reminder")
      .where("user", "==", user)
      .get()
      .then((remindersRecord) => {
        remindersRecord.forEach((reminderDoc) => {
          console.log(reminderDoc.data());
        });
      });
```

I am trying to get the "reminders" data of the connected user, the query works since we got reminderDoc which contain a bunch of objects, and inside there is the data I want but when I call data() nothing changes, I don't get the document it returns the same object.

Reminder collection :
[image]

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Inside an unique reminder doc, is there an attribute call data?

Comment: no i just edited the question and put a screenshot of the collection

Comment: In here I think you should get every document data object which are equals to your user. If that user have 5 reminders then there should be 5 console logs with big objects. Is it?

Comment: well it goes inside the loop and it shows on the console foreach reminder

Comment: Yeah. Then what do you need to get?

Comment: the data not the whole object which contains all the firebase and auth objects as if data() didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to replicate this on my side and I think this is working fine. I think that result that you get is related with fields `boss` and `user` which I guess are `reference` type in firestore. If you log to console such fields give results like this:

```
{
  reference: DocumentReference {
    _firestore: Firestore {
      _settings: [Object],
      _settingsFrozen: true,
      _serializer: [Serializer],
      _projectId: <PROJECT_ID>,
      registeredListenersCount: 0,
      bulkWritersCount: 0,
      _backoffSettings: [Object],
      _clientPool: [ClientPool]
    },
    _path: ResourcePath { segments: [Array] },
    _converter: {
      toFirestore: [Function: toFirestore],
      fromFirestore: [Function: fromFirestore]
    }
  },
  text_field: 'test',
  ...
  
}
```

So for presented example you will get 2 such fields and for those fields you will not see as a string. BTW the timestamp field will not be shown properly as well.
To avoid this issue you can use example `path` [property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#path) of document reference or when it comes to timestamp you can use `toDate()` [method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#todate). I have created small example to show the fields properly (looping over all the object fields):

```
remindersRecord.forEach((reminderDoc) => {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(reminderDoc.data())) {
       if (key == 'boss' || key == 'user')  console.log(`${key}: ${value.path}`)
       else if (key == 'startAt') console.log(`${key}: ${value.toDate()}`)
       else console.log(`${key}: ${value}`)
});
```

I tested this in nodejs directly, but it should work in `componentDidMount` as well.